# PhpWord add table in header/footer

Tags: phpword

When i add into header or footer table - i get one column.

Looks like in header/footer is ignored addRow() method.

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

    $section = $phpWord->addSection();
    $header = $section->addHeader();
    $table = $header->addTable(['columnWidths' => 200, 'borderColor' => '000000', 'borderWidth' => 5]);
    $table->addRow(200);
    $table->addCell(100)->addText("Col 1");
    $table->addCell(100)->addText("Col 2");

    $table->addRow(200);
    $table->addCell(100)->addText("Col 1");
    $table->addCell(100)->addText("Col 2");
```

So why not working my table?

Comment: It is not completely clear what your issue is, i.e. on one hand you say that you get one column but on other hand you say that addRow method looks to be ignored. I quickly tested the above code and with phpword 0.13.0 version and opened it up with libreoffice and it creates two rows and two columns (albeit quite small columns).

Comment: "it creates two rows and two columns" - this is what it need. Do you test it in page body or header? I have problems only with header/footer. When add this table to page body - works fine.

Comment: I tested it as you have written it above, i.e. in header